# What will happen when ESP == EBP

Tags: assembly, x86, buffer-overflow

As you all know the stack grows from high memory location to low memory location.

ESP → Points top of the stack 
EBP → Points bottom of the stack

When ESP > EBP, buffer overflow happens. So what will happen when ESP == EBP?

Comment: `EBP` does not point to bottom of the stack. It points to wherever you set it to point.

Comment: Suppose I am calling the function? Will EBP set to something now? If yes, then kindly answer my question, otherwise, when will EBP set

Comment: No, calling a function does not change EBP. The function itself might use it as a frame pointer, or as a general purpose register. Also, standard calling conventions mandate EBP be preserved so the caller sees no change.

Comment: EBP is just an auxilliary register to help manipulate the ESP. In x86 i'ts auto segmented to SS: , so that's why it's used instead of another register.

Comment: Did you mean *stack underflow* instead of *buffer overflow*?  Underflow is hard to get on a call stack, and if you do, it is almost certainly caused by some other (accidental or malicious) memory overwrite error rather than underflow by the call chain. The hardware does not detect stack underflow directly from the ESP register, but may detect memory accesses to addresses that are too high for the established stack.

Comment: *So what will happen when ESP == EBP* Nothing; if you're talking about using EBP as a frame pointer, it means your function just set up EBP as a frame pointer and hasn't reserved any space in its stack frame yet.  [explanation about push ebp and pop ebp instruction in assembly](//stackoverflow.com/q/3638075)

Comment: @ErikEidt Interesting. I was watching The Cyber Mentor's Video, [Start Here](https://youtu.be/qSnPayW6F7U?t=97). There he used to EBP at last. AFAIK, EIP is overwritten through a buffer overflow. If I am wrong, correct me

Comment: Yes, buffer overrun is an exploit that can purposefully corrupt the call stack and hence the integrity of the call chain.